# Google Custom Search Engine with IE6

Tags: css, search, internet-explorer-6

I am trying to use Google Custom Search (Business Edition) on my site. I am not using the iFrame but I am using the Custom Element. I selected a theme and everything looks fine in all the browsers except IE6. All the search results are taking the Promotion CSS.

**Update - Posted Code**

```
<div id="cse-search-form" style="width: 100%;">Loading</div>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('search', '1');
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('XXXXXXXX');
    customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
    var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
    options.setSearchFormRoot('cse-search-form');

    options.setAutoComplete(true);
    customSearchControl.draw('cse', options);
  }, true);
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.google.com/cse/style/look/minimalist.css" type="text/css" />


<div id="cse" style="width:100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Please post a description of what doesn't work, a demo link or a screen shot.

Comment: In IE6, the results all look like promotions. I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong with the implementation because if you log into Google CSE with IE6 and check the Preview, you can confirm what I am saying. This happens on any theme but I am trying to use the Minimalist theme

Comment: Post some code for us to see. We're not magic.

Comment: Hi...I posted the code above. It is the default code provided by Google CSE to include the Google Custom Search box on a site. You can see at the bottom that a stylesheet is included to style the results and search box. The results in Internet Explorer 6 look as if they are all Promotions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. The issue was with CSS that Google provides. They no longer support IE6 and infact do not have the browser installed anywhere to test (or so I've been told).

The issue is with IE6 and its inability to support multiple classes. Have a look at [Ryan Brill's post](http://www.ryanbrill.com/archives/multiple-classes-in-ie) for more information. To get the Google Custom Search CSS to work with IE6, the CSS selectors have to be tweaked a bit.

Ex:  `div.gs-promotion{ }` instead of .`cse .gs-promotion.gs-result, .gs-promotion.gs-result{ }`